# How to invoke function constructor through constructor property instead of new

Tags: javascript, constructor

```
function Test(){
    var aVariable =1;
    this.bVaribale = 2;
    this.say = function(){
        console.log(this.bVaribale);
    }
}

var t1 = new Test();
var t2 = Test.constructor();

t1.say();
t2.say();
```

Last rows produces `Uncaught TypeError: t2.say is not a function(…)`

How to invoke function constructor through constructor property?

Comment: Nononono. `Test` is a `Function` instance

Comment: *Test.constructor* is the built–in Function constructor. Perhaps you mean `t1.constructor`. But calling *Test* as a function doesn't set its *this* to a new instance of *Test* and it returns *undefined*, not *this*.

Answer (score 0):

Should be...

```
function Test(){
    this.bVariable = 2;
    this.say = function(){
        console.log(this.bVariable);
    }
}

var t1 = new Test();
var t2 = new Test.prototype.constructor();
// or var t2 = new t1.constructor();

// both work
t1.say();
t2.say();
```

See, `Test` itself is a fine object (a Function, to be specific). With `Test.constructor` you access the constructor function of this object - a global `Function` function:

```
console.log(Test.constructor === Function); // true
```

You seem to be looking for `constructor` property of *objects* created with `Test`. That means you should either query `t1.constructor` (if you know those objects), or `Test.prototype` if you know the function itself. The latter case seem to be strange (what's beneficial in accessing `something` via `something.prototype.constructor`?)

Note that you still should use `new` keyword here to set up a proper context. The alternative is using [ES6 Reflect API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect) - to be more specific, [Reflect.construct](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect/construct):

```
var t2 = Reflect.construct(Test, []);
```

... which seems to already have been implemented in major browsers.

Answer (score 0):

The `constructor` property points to the constructor function used to construct the instance on which you access `constructor`.

It's not the internal [[Construct]] method!

Since `Test` is a `Function`, `Test.constructor === Function`.

You may want `Reflect.construct` instead:

```
Reflect.construct(Test, [])
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not a best practice to call own property like a built-in property.
For reaching your goal you can do something like this:

```
function Test() {
   return {
     create: function() {
       return new Test();
     }
   };
}
```

And call it

```
Test().create()
```